# Как исправить и воспроизвести баг верстки на андроид 4.2 (HTC)?

Tags: mobile, android, html, вёрстка, css

Всем привет.

Сверстал  [страничку](http://lending-page.tamada24.ru/), а заказчик говорит, что у него не отображются картинки, и показывает скрин:

[image]

Однако у меня никак не получилось воспроизвести ни на одном из телефонов, даже на втором андроиде.
Собственно, как выловить эту ерунду и пофиксить?

P.S. Если вы перешли по ссылке с телефона, отпишитесь в комменты модель телефона и версию системы.

Comment: Android 5, Note III, Opera - всё валидно.  
P. S. Про браузер не нужно забывать - он всё-таки рендерит (или не рендерит :)).  
P. P. S. В эмуляторах разных моделей и ОСей тоже норм.

Comment: Посоветуйте заказчику включить показ картинок в настройках браузера.

Comment: некоторые картинки все же показываются. Я посмотрел размеры картинок. Некоторые - полмегабайта. Если у заказчика gprs, то такие картинки будут долго грузиться. Да и сам сервер также подтормаживает. 3 секунды грузить сайт, на котором, собственно, ничего и нет (интернет у меня не модемовский, если что:))